# can't delete directory under linux due to broken files

Tags: linux, system-administration, rm

```
kt@rails-ubuntu:~/rails/ledger/releases/20080820144914/.git/hooks$ ls -al
ls: cannot access post-commit: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access update: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access post-update: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access commit-msg: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access pre-rebase: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access post-receive: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access pre-applypatch: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access pre-commit: No such file or directory
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 kt kt 4096 2008-09-09 18:10 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 kt kt 4096 2008-09-09 18:10 ..
-????????? ? ?         ?            ?                ? commit-msg
-????????? ? ?         ?            ?                ? post-commit
-????????? ? ?         ?            ?                ? post-receive
-????????? ? ?         ?            ?                ? post-update
-????????? ? ?         ?            ?                ? pre-applypatch
-????????? ? ?         ?            ?                ? pre-commit
-????????? ? ?         ?            ?                ? pre-rebase
-????????? ? ?         ?            ?                ? update
```

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Although it isn't a direct programming question, it falls under the umbrella of "of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere" (see the faq) since it relates to an environmental issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, here's your question, nicely formatted (surround it in < pre > tags to get this):

```
kt@rails-ubuntu:~/rails/ledger/releases/20080820144914/.git/hooks$ ls -al
ls: cannot access post-commit: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access update: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access post-update: No such file or directory
[snip]
```

Anyway, you need to boot up in single-user mode and run fsck. If you can't reboot right now, just move the directory to /tmp and forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Looks like you have some kind of filesystem problems; I'd recommend you run fsck and see if it finds anything

(b) Really not a programming-related question, so off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem caused by Aptana Studio working with rails more than once.
 The long term solution was to avoid using aptana to create files.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and tried everything. Surprisingly the solution is very simple. Dude, this is what you do:
Using GUI and not the terminal
1. Move all other files in that folder to a different one with a different name
2. Move the containing directory which should have only the problematic file to trash
3 Empty trash

and yes, it is that simple